# Is there a WebGL equivalent to async System.Net/System.Net.Sockets methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await

Hi all hoping someone can help me with this,

I'm trying to build my Unity project in WebGL but I've come to the realisation that using System.Net/System.Net.Sockets isn't supported and I need some alternative functions that do the same things (My Knowledge is pretty lacking on the subject of handling async calls in Unity but got the Google sample code working to my delight)

Now in my Windows build the code is (reduced as much as I could but here is the link to the google sample which has the full code (excluding minor changes to make it work in Unity -> [Google Oauth example](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/tree/master/OAuthDesktopApp)

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public void btnclickWindows(){
    button_Click_Windows("hello");
}

public async void button_Click_Windows(object sender){

    string redirectURI = string.Format("http://localhost:8887/", IPAddress.Loopback,        GetRandomUnusedPort());

    var http = new HttpListener();
    http.Prefixes.Add(redirectURI);

    http.Start();

    string authorizationRequest = string.Format("{0}?access_type=offline&prompt=consent&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&state={3}&code_challenge={4}&code_challenge_method={5}",
           authorizationEndpoint,
           System.Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectURI),
           clientID,
           state,
           code_challenge,
           code_challenge_method
           );


    // Opens request in the browser.
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(authorizationRequest);

    var context = await http.GetContextAsync();

    var response = context.Response;
}
```

So this works perfect in Windows etc but not WebGL, the main functions that aren't supported are
`IPAddress.Loopback var http = new HttpListener(); System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(authorizationRequest); var context = await http.GetContextAsync();`

Does anyone know of a way or library that I can use within WebGL that runs each one of these functions?